# Magento 2.4 Header and footer not showing in Email template

Tags: magento2, email-templates, header, footer

I have create one custom module and in this module I have created send email functionality. But In Email header and footer is not send.

So Please help me.

**`THANKS.`**

Answer (score 0):

If you are use send email functionally using controller and other like :-

My Old code is not working header and footer

```
$transport = $this->transportBuilder
                    ->setTemplateIdentifier('admin_customerapprove_template')
                    ->setTemplateOptions(
                        [
                            'area' => \Magento\Framework\App\Area::AREA_FRONTEND,
                            'store' => \Magento\Store\Model\Store::DEFAULT_STORE_ID,
                        ]
                    )
                    ->setTemplateVars([
                        'customerName'  => $customerFirstName ,
                        'customerEmail'  => $customerEmail,
                    ])
                    ->setFrom($sender)
                    ->addTo($emailSender)
                    ->getTransport();
                $transport->sendMessage();
                $this->inlineTranslation->resume();
```

After i have find some solution like :-

**for**

```
'store' => \Magento\Store\Model\Store::DEFAULT_STORE_ID
```

**use**

```
'store' => $this->storeManager->getStore()->getId()
```

And How to create object for storeManager follow below link :-

https://www.mageplaza.com/devdocs/how-get-store-information-magento-2.html

Hope this help other.

**`THANKS.`**